# how to use one apache camel context object in each java Restful services

Tags: java, apache-camel, restful-architecture

i need to perform the all operation like the creating the quartz-2 scheduler and deleting on only one Apache camel context 
using restful service. when i try using following code .each time its creating the new context object. i do not know how to fix it or where i need to initiate the apache camel context object.

this is my code

this is my java restful services which is call to the quartz scheduler.

java Rest Services.

```
  @Path("/remainder") 
  public class RemainderResource { 
    private static org.apache.log4j.Logger log = Logger.getLogger(RemainderResource.class); 
    RemainderScheduler remainderScheduler=new RemainderScheduler(); 
    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext(); 
    @POST 
    @Path("/beforeday/{day}") 
    public void create(@PathParam("day") int day,final String userdata) 
    { 
            log.debug("the starting process of the creating the Remainder"); 
            JSONObject data=(JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(userdata); 
            String cronExp=data.getString("cronExp");   
            remainderScheduler.create(cronExp,day,context); 

    } 
}
```

This is my java class which is schedule job .

```
    public class RemainderScheduler { 


    private static org.apache.log4j.Logger log = Logger.getLogger(RemainderScheduler.class); 

    public void sendRemainder(int day) 
    { 
            log.debug("the starting of the sending the Remainder to user"); 

    } 

    public RouteBuilder createMyRoutes(final String cronExp,final int day) 
    { 
        return new RouteBuilder() 
        { 
            @Override 
            public void configure() throws Exception { 
            log.debug("Before set schedulling"); 
                 from("quartz2://RemainderGroup/Remainder? cron="+cronExp+"&deleteJob=true&job.name='RemainderServices'").bean(new RemainderScheduler(), "sendRemainder('"+day+"')").routeId("Remainder") 
                 .process(new Processor() { 
                @Override 
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception { 

                } 
            }) 
                 ; 
                 log.debug("after set schedulling"); 

            } 
        }; 
    } 

    public void stopService(CamelContext context) 
    { 
            log.debug("this is going to be stop the route"); 
            try { 
                    context.stopRoute("Remainder"); 
                    context.removeRoute("Remainder"); 
            } catch (Exception e) { 
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
            } 

    } 
    public void create(final String cronExp,final int day,CamelContext context) 
    { 
            try 
     { 
            //this for if all ready exist then stop it. 
                    if(context.getRoute("Remainder")!=null) 
                            stopService(context); 

                    log.debug("the starting of the process for creating the Remaider Services");    
                    context.addRoutes(createMyRoutes(cronExp, day)); 
                    context.start();    
                     log.debug("the status for removing the services                      is"+context.removeRoute("Remainder")); 
           } 
        catch(Exception e) 
         { 
           System.out.println(e.toString()); 
           e.printStackTrace(); 
           } 
      } 
 }
```

if i execute the above code then the each java Restful request create the new context object.
and its will start the job scheduling on new apache camel context object. and if send request for stop the route then also its creating the new apache context object so i am not able to reset or stop the quartz-2 scheduler.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good practise to create a camel context per request.
I suggest you to use [camel-restlet](http://camel.apache.org/restlet.html) or [camel-cxfrs](http://camel.apache.org/cxfrs.html) to delegate the request of create and delete scheduler to another camel context.